# Ext JS: Designing a base class and override it

Tags: javascript, class, mvvm, component, extjs

I'm trying to define a **base class** and override it's `items` on different inherited sub-classes. I'm following **MVVM** pattern to fetch records from backend. Created several `stores` and `formulas` within ViewModel.

```
+---------------+---------------+
| NUMBER value  |               |
+---------------+  GLYPH value  |       
| STRING value  |               |
+---------------+---------------+
```

Depends on structure above Base Class as pseudocode;

- Should have a special **layout** for items as drawed above. *(Could be design with css as well)*
- Those 3 values will be bindable/changeable for each inherited class and 3 of values will be binding with ViewModel's `bind` config.
- Includes several default configs: width, height, border ...

On the inhetired class;

- Of course firstly calls defaults of Base class.
- Defines `viewModel` config for called one.
- Those bindable values should be customize on here with `{bind descriptor}` through **`items`** config or some another way.

I've defined a basic structure for this base class and a sample inherited one but currently couldn't be success to render data to screen. Here is mentioned code block on Sencha [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ffn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved to my aim through another post on Stackoverflow. Only needs some CSS adjustments thats all.

Here you may examine answers and Fiddle samples;

> [Ext JS: tpl config is ignoring html in Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817253/ext-js-tpl-config-is-ignoring-html-in-panel)